# Grammars in compilers

Tags: compiler-construction

How to generate rules to translate 1 form of grammar into another??

for example:

GRAMMAR 1:

```
BLOCK: while ( id:=N) { BLOCK } | id:=N
N: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

GRAMMAR 2:

```
BLOCK: while id:=N DO BLOCK END | id:=N
N: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

I want 2 generate a translation such that I can translate a statement in Grammar 2 into the corresponding statement in Grammar 1...

Comment: Give us some more detail about the syntax tree and how you created it?

Comment: Fundamentally you want to build a full language translator.  That's simply not an easy task, even if you  have two grammars in your possession.  If nothing else, you have to handle the *semantic* differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, create a parser that converts a sentence from Grammar 1 into a syntax tree, and then convert the syntax tree back into a sentence in Grammar 2?

Comment: created the syntax tree. But how to make it 'convert' into a sentence in grammar 2??

Comment: If the two grammars are equivalent, then you simply need to traverse the tree, and generate the string as you go.

Comment: Hmm thanx. :) But cant we write some translation rules?? It would be helpful if you write some sample rules for me..

Comment: What do you mean by "translation rules"?  If the two grammars are similar enough, then perhaps you can get away with a simple string search-and-replace.  If not, then you'll have to go via some intermediate representation (a syntax tree seems like the obvious choice).